# Prove a map of binary expansion is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, binary

Prove that the map: f: $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} \times \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ $\to$ $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is continuous.

I know that the map can be written as ($m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4,...$) $\times$ ($n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4,...$) $\mapsto$ ($0.m_1m_2m_3m_4...,0.n_1n_2n_3n_4...$) as binary expansions, and f is surjective, but how do I show it is continuous?

Comment: It seems you are missing a "$0.$" in front of the second component, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: It suffices to check that 
$$F : \{ 0,1\}^{\mathbb N} \to [0,1],\ \ \ F(m_1, m_2, \cdots, ) = 0.m_1m_2\cdots $$
is continuous. Let $V\subset [0,1]$ be an open set. First of all, show that $F^{-1}(V)$ is open when

$$V = \left(\frac{m_1}{2} + \frac{m_2}{2^2} + \cdots + \frac{m_k}{2^k}, \frac{m_1}{2} + \frac{m_2}{2^2} + \cdots + \frac{m_k}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^k} \right),$$

where $k\in \mathbb N$ and $m_1, \cdots, m_k \in \{0,1\}$. Then the general $U$ can be written as countable union of these $V$'s.

Comment: If $$V = \left(\frac{m_1}{2} + \frac{m_2}{2^2} + \cdots + \frac{m_k}{2^k}, \frac{m_1}{2} + \frac{m_2}{2^2} + \cdots + \frac{m_k}{2^k} + \frac{1}{2^k} \right),$$, then $V\subset [0,1] \times [0,1]$, how could $V\subset [0,1]$?

Comment: Oops, this is an open interval, just like $(1/2, 1) \subset [0,1]$. @gne3421

Comment: Thanks, does the general $U$ denote $\{0,1\}^\Bbb{N}$ here? I'm also having trouble to show how the inverse of V is open...

Comment: @gne3421 : Try to start with the simple one: Can you show that $F^{-1}(V)$ is open when $V = (1/2, 1)$? ($U$ should be an open set in $[0,1]$)

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do it. First, note that as John Ma noted, it suffices to show continuity of
$$
F : \{0,1\}^\Bbb{N}\to [0,1], (x_n)_n \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n/2^n.
$$

To see this, show that each of the maps
$$
F_N : \{0,1\}^\Bbb{N}\to [0,1], (x_n)_n \mapsto \sum_{n=1}^N x_n/2^n
$$
is continuous (use that each projection on the individual components is continuous) and that $F_N \to F$ **uniformly**, e.g. by the Weierstrass M-Test.

You can even use a similar approach to show directly that your map is continuous.